# connect-multiparty middle get files request as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to upload image files to the serve with the help of [`connect-multiparty`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty)

```
router.post('/image', multipartMiddleware , function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, req.file);
});

<form method="post" action="/products/image">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

But the result of the above console is `{ file: '156.jpg' } undefined`, i.e. I can get the file name, but why the file object is not coming?

Answer (score 1):

The file content is located in `req.files` not `req.file` in your code.

And the file path and file name can also be found

```
    var tmppath = req.files.file.path;
    var tmpname = req.files.file.name;
```

Here is one [link](https://github.com/richzw/CodeHome/blob/master/JavaScript/upload.js), which I used to upload file with `Node.js`.

Comment: I didn't use native file upload so my object is different, I figured that out anyway. I'm using base64 so the approach is abit different, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700883/base64-image-corrupted-uploading-to-s3