# base64 image corrupted uploading to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3

```
router.post('/image', multipartMiddleware , function(req, res) {

   var file_name = req.body.name;
   var data = req.body.data;

   return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file_name , data , 'base64').then(function (err) { 

        res.status(200).end();
    });

});
```

What's wrong in my code above? There's no error in my therminal, I have the file in my s3 but it's corrupted when I download it.

Comment: Can an image encoded in base64 be opened from a file?  I always assumed that only worked for inline images.  When you examine the file with a text or hex editor, does it look like base64?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You can set the header `Content-Encoding=base64`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26111627/511200. Not sure we can answer OP's question since we have no idea what `s3fsImpl` is.

Comment: @danneu https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3fs

Comment: @danneu Also I'm seeing the file which been uploaded to s3 is base64 since I pass 'base64' in the writeFile function.

Answer (score 11):

Since I don't know what `s3fsImpl` is in your code, I can't answer this to your implementation but here's how I would do it using aws-sdk:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const file_name = req.body.name;
const data = req.body.data;
// We need to get the format of the file from the base64 string i.e. data:image/png;base64<base64String>
const format = data.substring(data.indexOf('data:')+5, data.indexOf(';base64'));

// We need to get the actual file data from the string without the base64 prefix
const base64String = data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
const buff = new Buffer(base64String,'base64');

s3.upload({
    Bucket:'s3-bucket-name',
    Key: file_name, 
    Body: buff, 
    ContentEncoding:'base64',
    ContentType:format
}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   });
```

Comment: where is base64Img variable

Comment: you are right, it should've been data not base64Img